# How to use expression values in where condition?

Tags: model, eav, query

How to do that in magento model way

```
Select sum(qty + product_id - any_other_columns) as total from table2  where total>10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a strange query you want to run, but this is how you do it:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('total' => new Zend_Db_Expr("at_qty.qty - e.entity_id")));
$collection->getSelect()->having('total > 10');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to use Direct mysql in Magento

```
/**
 * Get the resource model
 */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/**
 * Retrieve the write connection
 */
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

/**
 * Retrieve our table name
 */
$table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');

/**
 * Set the product ID
 */
$productId = 44;

/**
 * Set the new SKU
 * It is assumed that you are hard coding the new SKU in
 * If the input is not dynamic, consider using the
 * Varien_Db_Select object to insert data
 */
$newSku = 'new-sku';

$query = "UPDATE {$table} SET sku = '{$sku}' WHERE entity_id = "
         . (int)$productId;

/**
 * Execute the query
 */
$writeConnection->query($query);
```

[For More see here.](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

**Another way**

```
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'product_url', 'small_image'))
   ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'UX%'))
    ->load();
```

[For more detail see here.](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/)

Comment: you didn't read my question i think

Comment: I have read your question and these are just examples now what do you want ?